# Ideal way to use graphql

Tags: graphql

I am new user for graphql. I am planning to use graphql as a middleware layer where different application will hit the API and get the data they require. But main problem is training different groups as to how to post data and query the data they require. Is is good idea to build a middleware which accepts JSON over REST api and converts it to graphql request. I am thinking of 2 options 
1. Build REST middle layer which accepts JSON and convert it to graphql request.
2. Ask user to get comfortable with graphql.

Comment: Assuming you have an existing REST API (which itself is a bit unclear from your question), this question really boils down to whether the benefits of adapting GraphQL outweigh the costs of having the consumers of your API learn a new technology. That's not something anyone other than you can answer.

Comment: We don't have any API. This will be new. Team is mots comfortable with REST calls.

Comment: Either way this question is not one someone on SO could provide an answer for. Your team will need to look at the [pros and cons of implementing GraphQL](https://www.robinwieruch.de/why-graphql-advantages-disadvantages-alternatives) and decide whether the advantages outweigh the cost of learning a new technology.

Answer (score 0):

Mixing REST and graphql is never a good idea for a new project, because you will waste your resources for doing the same thing in two different ways and you will have to maintain larger codebase. Providing REST and graphql at the same time may seems like a convenience for your customers but in the long run, it is not. Smaller, well structured and well documented API is always preferable.

If you are going to mix and match different resources or call outside services graphql offers better solution. Graphql provides strong typing, single round trip, query batching, instrospection and better dev tools, versionless API.